# Formula for number of rows from a x4 grid

Tags: math, formula

Ok so I am currently setting up a grid, each row will have 4 objects. The number of rows must be calculated according to this constraint.

So if I had 15 objects, I need 4 rows. 
If i had 12 objects I need 3 rows.

Somehow I need some sort of mathematical formula that will perform and return this number. So when I say to the function I have x number of objects, it will return the number of rows.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Well what you describe is an operator called division :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Warning: readability swamp

> floor((obj - 1) / 4) + 1

where obj is the number of objects in your question.

or even more concise:

> floor((obj + 3) / 4)

One liner!

Floor usually comes with the language's integer division operator (e.g, Java, C++), so it's probably shorter to implement.

Comment: ...or just use the ceiling function instead.

Comment: You have reinvented the ceiling function, minus the clarity ;).

Answer (score 2):

```
ceil(x / 4.0)
```

You want the ceiling, not the floor of the resultant value. Otherwise, you won't be able to fit say 15 into 4 rows.

Comment: I'd be frank: this is better. Actually I feel stupid for not thinking of this better one. +1